# How to get certificate issuer name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl

I am trying to figure out how to correctly get the issuer name of `er.lazada.sg` as reflected in google chrome as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

I have attempted to use the ruby code below, but its output is not identical. It shows GlobalSign instead of Encryption Everywhere.

```rb
# Get OpenSSL context
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new

# Get remote TCP socket
sock = TCPSocket.new('er.lazada.sg', 443)

# pass that socket to OpenSSL
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)

# establish connection, if possible
ssl.connect

# get peer certificate and do things with it
cert = ssl.peer_cert
cert.version
cert.issuer

# The output is #<OpenSSL::X509::Name CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE>
```

I have attempted to get the issuer name via python and it successfully got "Encryption Everywhere".

```py
import ssl, socket

hostname = 'er.lazada.sg'

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()

with ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname) as s:
    s.connect((hostname, 443))
    cert = s.getpeercert()

subject = dict(x[0] for x in cert['subject'])

issued_to = subject['commonName']

issuer = dict(x[0] for x in cert['issuer'])

issued_by = issuer['commonName']

# The output is {'countryName': 'US', 'organizationName': 'DigiCert Inc', 'organizationalUnitName': 'www.digicert.com', 'commonName': 'Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1'}
```

I am wondering why the result is different in the two languages and how can I get the correct issuer name in Ruby...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the server hostname used for SNI.

```
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)
ssl.hostname = 'er.lazada.sg' # Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Can you explain how this worked?

Comment: You need to indicate which hostname you are attempting to connect to so that the server can send you the right certificate. Apparently, Python does this for you, but Ruby does not.